# HTML DIV's showing identical input

Tags: javascript, html, css, sockets

I have 4 fields on the front end which display item name and item price.

```
 <div class="itemBoxWrapper">
          <div class="item1Wrapper">
              <div class="item1Title"></div>
              <div class="item1Price"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item2Wrapper">
              <div class="item2Title"></div>
              <div class="item2Title"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

For the 1st item, the name and price fields come up as expected.
For the 2nd Item, the price instead also displays the data for the item name
so it says item name for both the name and price fields for the second item, but the code looks identical to the 1st item which works? The css is also identical.

```
 $('.customerName').text('Customer name: ' + customerName);
            $('.orderNum').text('Order number: ' + orderNum);

            $('.item1Title').text('Item name: ');
            $('.item1Price').text('Price: ' + item1Price);

            $('.item2Title').text('2nd Item name: ');
            $('.item2Price').text('Price ' + item2Price);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct your code to this:

```
 <div class="itemBoxWrapper">
          <div class="item1Wrapper">
              <div class="item1Title"></div>
              <div class="item1Price"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item2Wrapper">
              <div class="item2Title"></div>
              <div class="item2Price"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

In your second wrapper, you wrote `item2Title` twice instead of `item2Title` and `item2Price`.

Comment: Thanks Goran :) I noticed not soon after posting, I'll come back to approve the answer! I'm really glad I posted, I can't believe how obvious it is?